# How can I convert YYWW to date format based on day[Ex: Monday's date in given YYWW ] in SqlServer?

Tags: sql-server, date, format

I have a column in my table with `YYWW` format. I need to convert this `YYWW` and get Monday's date.

For Example:

```
Input YYWW: 1847
Expected Output: 2018-11-19 [Monday's date in 2018 Week 47]
```

Thanks in advance

I tried the below but does not work properly

```
declare @value int = 1519
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(YEAR, 2000 + @value / 100-1900, 7 * (@value % 100)-7), 105);   



1851 -Expected 17-12-2018[Monday] Works fine for this year 2018

1752 -Expected 25-12-2017[Monday] but shows 24-12-2017 [Sunday]

1652 -Expected 26-12-2016 [Monday] but shows 24-12-2016 [Saturday]

1519 -Expected 04-05-2015 [Monday] but shows 07-05-2015  [Thursday]
```

Comment: What attempts have you made so far? What is the lowest value that the first digits can have? Should be, for example, assume 7021 is 1970 or 2070?

Comment: Year is always in between 2000 and 2100

Comment: Also, do you have a calendar table? Depending on where/who you are, the start of the week varies.

Comment: Ok, we still need to see your attempt then please.

Comment: Edited Post with my trials. Please have a look. Thanks!

Comment: How exactly do you define the "first" week? What is the expected output for `1501`, `1601`, `1701` and `1801`?

Comment: @SalmanA my answer will return the iso_week result. I assume this is the same as requested. `2014-12-29,2016-01-04,2017-01-02,2018-01-01`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @t table(YYWW char(4))
INSERT @t values('1847'),('1752'),('1652'),('1519')

SELECT 
  CAST(DATEADD(wk,RIGHT(YYWW,2)+DATEDIFF(d,0,DATEADD(
       d,-4,LEFT(YYWW,2)+'0101'))/7,0) as date)
FROM @t
```

Result:

```
2018-11-19
2017-12-25
2016-12-26
2015-05-04
```

EDIT:

To get the requested format DD-MM-YYYY:

```
SELECT 
  CONVERT(CHAR(10),DATEADD(wk,RIGHT(YYWW,2)+DATEDIFF(d,0,DATEADD(
       d,-4,LEFT(YYWW,2)+'0101'))/7,0),105)
FROM @t
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Clausen!

Comment: t-clausen.dk, One question, is there any code I need to use to format date from YYYY-MM-DD to DD-MM-YYYY? What changes needed in the above script for this format DD-MM-YYYY?

Answer (score 1):

I would, personally, use a [calendar table](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/calendar/145206/). Then you can do something like:

```
SELECT YT.YYWW,
       CT.[date]
FROM YourTable YT
     JOIN CalendarTable CT ON CT.[Year] = '20'+LEFT(YT.YYWW,2)
                          AND CT.WeekNo = RIGHT(YT.YYWW,2)
                          AND CT.DayOfWeek = 1; --Assumes Monday is day 1.
```

Comment: The calendar table you are refering to in your link, is using sunday as day 1 of the week

Comment: @t-clausen.dk Calendar Tables are personalised for a business'/user's need and preference; just because the link has Sunday as day 1, doesn't mean that the OP's will. The link is simply a template.

Answer (score 0):

I think your calc may be off week 47 of 2018 starts on 2018-11-26 which is a Monday.

in any case the following should work if you disagree with the above simply subtract 1 from the number of weeks

```
DECLARE @Date date
DECLARE @Year int = 2000 +18
declare @week int = 47

SET @Date = DATEADD(YEAR, @Year - 1900, 0)

SELECT dateadd(ww,@week-1,DATEADD(DAY, (@@DATEFIRST - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @Date) +  (8 - @@DATEFIRST) * 2) % 7, @Date))
```

Comment: sorry my bad week 47 is actually 2018-11-19 so you will need to subtract 1 from @week - have edited the answer to reflect

Comment: This will not always return the correct result. **@@DATEFIRST** is not reliable and should be avoided. It depends of local settings and can give different results on different computers. Usually you need **SET DATEFIRST** to make it work. Much easier to avoid it

Comment: @@DATEFIRST is session not computer dependent, additionally the code works by using @@DATEFIRST to find the first Monday of the year and will work for all session settings.

Comment: Your code doesn't give the correct result for `1519`, the correct result result it `2015-05-04`, your code returns `2015-05-11`  yes - datefirst is session dependent, but for different servers it has different default values

Comment: Correct, I mistakenly assumed the first week of the year would always have a Monday.